# Failed to build OpenCL kernel: -11

Tags: nvidia, bumblebee, opencl

I have problems with OpenCl compilation.
For example, when I wan't to launch SmallptGPU :

> Usage: ./smallptGPU
>   Usage: ./smallptGPU   0 and power of 2)>    
>   OpenCL Platform 0: NVIDIA Corporation
>   OpenCL Device 0: Type = TYPE_GPU
>   OpenCL Device 0: Name = GeForce 840M
>   OpenCL Device 0: Compute units = 3
>   OpenCL Device 0: Max. work group size = 1024
>   [SELECTED] OpenCL Device 0: Type = TYPE_GPU
>   [SELECTED] OpenCL Device 0: Name = GeForce 840M
>   [SELECTED] OpenCL Device 0: Compute units = 3
>   [SELECTED] OpenCL Device 0: Max. work group size = 1024
>   Reading file 'rendering_kernel.cl' (size 3216 bytes)
>   Failed to build OpenCL kernel: -11
>   OpenCL Programm Build Log:

It returns the same error for every program I try to launch with OpenCL.
I have nvidia-346, nvidia-346-uvm, nvidia-modprobe, nvidia-opencl-icd-346 and opencl-headers installed and CUDA works fine.
My computer has two GPUs (an Intel one and the nVidia GPU) so I use bumblebee, and when I wan't to use CUDA, I load the nvidia-346-uvm module, and it works fine.
Can somebody help me to fix this issue ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It works now. I ran smallptGPU using strace and I saw that the program couldn't find libnvidia-compiler.so.346.72
I had to copy /usr/lib/nvidia-346/libnvidia-compiler.so* to /usr/lib/ and it works properly now.
The fact is that nvidia-346 and nvidia-346-uvm don't seem to copy/link their needed libraries to /usr/lib/, and that's true too for libvdpau.so for exemple ..